# How do I alter the list xpath gives back?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

```
mainCourse = tree.xpath('//div[@id="RM1127"]/div[@class="m01"]/text()')
```

I'm trying to extract a list of elements inside id RM1127. This gives me back a list. How do I make it insert a blank string when the class m01 doesn't exist in id RM1127?

I want to be able to tell whether it skipped over something.

Comment: could you provide example of input and what output you expect?

Comment: What you do here is taking all div with only [class = 'm01'] inside of div with [id='RM1127'], however it's not really clear what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The list contains only text nodes matching the XPath expression, it carries no information regarding elements the XPath didn't select whatsoever.

You need to write your own logic to insert blank string to the list in case *'class m01 doesn't exist in id RM1127'*. One possible approach is by modifying the XPath to select `div[@id="RM1127"]` so that you can loop through the complete set of the `div` and insert either actual target text or blank text into the list as needed, for example :

```
mainCourse = []
for div in tree.xpath('//div[@id="RM1127"]'):
    #store current list size
    size = len(mainCourse)
    #insert target text nodes to the list
    mainCourse.extend(div.xpath('./div[@class="m01"]/text()'))
    #if size doesn't change, meaning no target text nodes was found...
    if size == len(mainCourse):
        #...insert blank text to the list 
        mainCourse.append('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want, but it's going to be tricky in XPath 1.0 because (a) the only kind of collection you can return is a set of nodes, and (b) those nodes have to be nodes selected from the input document: you can't create anything new, like an empty string. Unless you can move to something more advanced than XPath 1.0 (e.g. XQuery) I think you're going to have to select more information than you want, and then filter it at the Python level.